# Using pow() gives errors

Tags: c++, math, cmath

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //int side1 = 0;
    //int side2 = 0;
    //int rightSide = 0;

    cout << "Right Side" << setw(10) << "Side1" << setw(10) << "Side2" << endl;

    for(int i=1;i<=500;i++)
    {
        //side1++;
        //cout << side1 << endl;

        for(int a=1;a<=500;a++)
        {
            //side2++;
            //cout << "side 2 " << side2 << endl;

            for(int c=1;c<=500;c++)
            {
                //rightSide++;
                int rightSideSqr = pow(c,c);
                int side1Sqr = pow(i,i);
                int side2Sqr = pow(a,a);

                if(rightSideSqr == (side1Sqr+side2Sqr))
                {
                    cout << rightSideSqr << setw(15) << i << setw(10) << a << endl;
                 }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives an error "PythagorialTriples.cpp:28: error: call of overloaded `pow(int&, int&)' is ambiguous". This doesn't happen if I simply used manual power like i*i, instead of the method. Can someone please explain me why this is happening? I am new to C++ anyway. Thanks

Comment: Power is causing problems again? That is because [the hearts of men are easily corrupted](http://www.hark.com/the-lord-of-the-rings-the-fellowship-of-the-ring/but-the-hearts-of-men-are-easily-corrupted).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple overloads for `pow` defined in `<cmath>`. In your code, these 3 are all equally valid, therefore the compiler is having trouble choosing the right one:

```
        pow(float, int);
        pow(double, int);
        pow(long double, int);
```

The simplest solution is to use `static_cast` on the first argument, to remove any ambiguity.  e.g.

```
int side1Sqr = pow( static_cast<double>(i) ,i );
int side2Sqr = pow( static_cast<double>(a) ,a );
```

Comment: Actually there are more than 3, but those are the only ones considered in this particular case.

Comment: @MarkRansom good point, thanks for that.  I've edited the answer accordingly!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I really appreciate it. However, I thought of using pow() thinking it will speed of the operation...But, it took 14 seconds while i*i took 1 seconds :(

Comment: `i*i` will be faster than `pow(i,2)` because: 1. `i*i` is integer math. 2. `pow(i,2)` does conversion and double math. FWIW, pow(int, int) works in g++.

Answer (score 4):

Whoa! Pow(x,y) is x raised to the yth power (in mathematical terms - x<sup>y</sup>)!! NOT x*y

So you're trying to take i<sup>ith</sup> power in a 500<sup>3</sup> nested loop. Probably not what you want. Replace with pow(i,2) for your desired behavior.

Note, @Mooing Duck raises an excellent point about x^y in c++ which is the XOR operator. But I think you sort of figured that out if you're already using `pow` anyway.

Comment: Careful, as `x^y` is valid C++ and means something _very_ different than what you say here.

Comment: Excellent point, especially with new C++ programmer. Fixing now.

Comment: I updated your question to use the `<sup>blah</sup>` tags to remove the `^` confusion issue.

Comment: Ah good call, I've gotta learn how to use the formatting tags better lol

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you can handle such a big pow?

Pow(x,y) is x<sup>y</sup>.  Look at the

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/

> double pow (      double base,      double exponent );
>
> long double pow ( long double base, long double exponent );
>
> float pow (       float base,       float exponent );
>
> double pow (      double base,         int exponent );
>
> long double pow ( long double base,         int exponent );

There is no INT version. Your compiler didnt know which one is correct. You have to tell them by using static_cast like:

```
int side1Sqr = pow(static_cast<double>i,i);
```

for big precision calculate you can use:

http://gmplib.org/

There is also one solution from boost.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot figure out which overloaded function to use.
Try

```
pow(double(i), i);
```

or

```
pow(double(i), 2);
```

Since that looks like what you want.

Comment: C-style casts should be avoided in C++.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco: Hi, this is interesting. Why that "easy" cast should be avoided?

Comment: `*_cast<type>` casts were specifically added to the C++ standard to avoid C-style (weak, unchecked) cast mistakes which are incredibly prevalent and have historically accounted for many, many bugs. The old-style cast remains in the standard mostly as a backward-compatibility, not as a language feature.